# Genymotion emulator black screen

Tags: virtualbox, emulator

I have installed the latest versions of Genymotion and Virtual box (Windows 10). However, when I install any device and then start, a black screen remains and does not open.

Any advice and tips on how to troubleshoot the situation are appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What does Virtualbox have to do with it?  Are you trying to run inside a VBox VM?  If so, that's not supported by Genymotion as it requires direct hardware access.

Comment: @essjae genymotion requires oracle virtual box to run